# node js and Pug

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

each guide in tour.guides

```
.overview-box__detail
          - if (guide && guide.photo)
            img.overview-box__img(src=`/img/users/${guide.photo}`, alt=`${guide.name}`)
          - else
            span No photo available
```

this is my code for getting the guide's properties from the guides but I can not get why  the error in the image keep poping
code for the tourmodel is

```
guides:[
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref:'User'
      }
[code for user model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhXw7.png)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use pug syntax instead of javascript:

```
if tour && tour.guides
    each guide in tour.guides
        .overview-box__detail
            if guide.photo
                img.overview-box__img(src='/img/users/' + guide.photo, alt=guide.name)
            else
                span No photo available
```